# $ABCD$ is a square with side-length $1$ and equilateral triangles $\Delta AYB$ and $\Delta CXD$ are inside the square. What is the length of $XY$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$ABCD$ is a square with side-length $1$ and equilateral triangles $\Delta AYB$ and $\Delta CXD$ are inside the square. What is the length of $XY$?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Have you tried drawing a diagram and thinking about the question in relation to the geometry? I would recommend changing the title - it means nothing - also "pls" is not a word.

Comment: [Read this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), please.

Answer (score 3):

First draw a diagram of the problem:

[image: Diagram]

Remember that angles in an equilateral triangle are all $60^\circ$ and each point is directly above the midpoint of the opposite side.

We can calculate the distance between $X$ and the midpoint of $AB$, let's call it $E$, using Pythagoras' Theorem:

\begin{align}(AE)^2+(EX)^2&=(AX)^2\\
\left(\frac 12\right)^2+(EX)^2&=1^2\\
\frac 14+(EX)^2&=1\\
EX^2&=\frac 34\\
EX&=\sqrt{\frac 34}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt3}2\end{align}

If we say $F$ is the midpoint of $CD$ then we can see that \begin{align}XF&=1-EX\\
&=1-\frac{\sqrt3}2\end{align}

Now, because of symmetry, we can say that $YE=1-\frac{\sqrt3}2$ as well

Therefore \begin{align}XY&=1-YE-XF\\
&=1-\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)-\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)\\
&=\sqrt 3-1\\
&\approx 0.73\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Just $2\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}-1$

Comment: I upvoted, since the effort in the answer is mirrored in the effort the OP placed into the question.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you!  I think my solution is better. It's just altitude-length twice minus side-length.